# Issues reading image from BytesIO() object using PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, bytesio

I am attempting to save an image in PNG format into a BytesIO object and read the same from buffer, but I get the following error:

**ValueError: not enough image data**

This is what I am attempting:

```
i = Image.open('sample_small.png') # Image.fromarray(img_array)
buf = BytesIO()
i = i.resize(size=(int(i.width/2), int(i.height/2)))
i.save(buf, format="PNG", compress_level=9)
buf.seek(0)
i = Image.frombuffer(data=buf.getvalue(), size=i.size, mode=i.mode, decoder_name="raw")
buf.close()

i.show()
```

could someone point out the right way to do this?

In the real use case, the original image is available as an array, so it is obtained by first loading the array as an Image using:

```
i = Image.fromarray(img_array)
```

The objective is to send the image to a zmq receiver as bytes object and hence I need to compress the image as PNG with max. compression,  store it into a temporary file-like object as bytes and then publish it using zmq, hence saving the image to a file and then loading the image to use `i.tobytes()` is also not optimal.

Since the receiver uses the Image.frombuffer()/ Image.frombytes() method to load the image, I want to know the right way to save the image data to a buffer that can be read by the receiver.

Thanks in advance!

The image I used in this example:

[image]

Comment: You're letting yourself be mystified by saving your PNG to a BytesIO like it's some kind of special file. All you did was make a PNG. So now that you have your PNG, do whatever PIL allows to convert it into bytes that `frombuffer`/`frombytes` can open. Just treat it like any other image file because that's exactly what it is.

Comment: Also, `frombuffer` expects pixel data, not a PNG. So whatever you have to do to get your PNG to be readable by `frombuffer` will result in it not being a PNG anymore. That said, do you really have to compress and reformat the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`frombuffer` is expecting pixel data, but you are giving it a compressed png. Since it's already a png file, `open` it.

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

def png_bytes(path:str, scale:float, compress_level:int=9) -> bytes:
    #image setup
    img = Image.open(path)
    img = img.resize(size=(int(img.width*scale), int(img.height*scale)))

    with BytesIO() as buff:
        #save png file to buff
        img.save(buff, format="PNG", compress_level=compress_level)
        
        #get bytes
        buff.seek(0) 
        out = buff.read()
        
    return out #return bytes


#get bytes
img = png_bytes('sample_small.png', .5)

#open bytes as BytesIO
Image.open(BytesIO(img)).show()
```

Comment: I already tried this and it works, but the issue is that the receiver uses Image.frombytes() or Image.frombuffer() to read images and I have no control over that. What would be the proper way to transmit compressed/resized png data that is compatible with frombuffer() ?

Answer (score 1):

[`Image.frombuffer`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombuffer) is exactly the wrong function to use for this; it says so right in the docs.

> Note that this function decodes pixel data only, not entire images. If you have an entire image file in a string, wrap it in a BytesIO object, and use open() to load it.

Note that `open` can take an open file instead of a filename, and a `BytesIO` object qualifies as a file..

Comment: I already gave this answer with code example and all, and deleted it because they are tied to the restraints of their receiver ONLY using `frombytes`/`frombuffer`. I'll undelete so you can see.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy then they need to listen to [Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76905787/5987).

Comment: @OneMadGypsy yes, that was my vote.  It's a good answer, even including some sample code.  Remember Stack Overflow isn't all about solving the problem of the moment, it's about leaving behind good information for all the people of the future to enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

If the recipient is going to use `frombytes()` to read the image, you need to use `tobytes()` to create it.

And the recipient will need to know, or be told, the image `mode` and `size`.